# Extend bootstrap select plugin

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-select

In my previous question I was talking about the bootstrap select plugin where the destroy method is doing something that I don't want. I edit manually the plugin but this is not a good practice.

[Bootstrap select destroy removes the original select from DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27333816/bootstrap-select-destroy-removes-the-original-select-from-dom/27334086?noredirect=1#comment43125298_27334086)

I would like to extend the plugin with a custom method so that it can do exactly wat I want.

I extend the plugin with folloing method:

```
$.extend(true, $.fn.selectpicker.prototype, {
    customRemove: function () {
        this.$newElement.remove();
        this.$element.show();
    }
});
```

This is located in another js file under the bootstrap select script file.

How do I call this new method? I tried the following without success:

```
$('select#begin' + _week + _day).selectpicker("customRemove");
```

or

```
$('select#begin' + _week + _day).selectpicker().customRemove();
```

Am I missing something?

The original method of the destroy function in the bootstrap select plugin:

```
remove: function () {
  this.$newElement.remove();
  this.$element.show();
}
```

Comment: Does `selectpicker()` return `this`? If not then you can't chain the method.

Comment: I see in the plugin `return this;` so yes

Comment: try selectpicker.prototype.customRemove();

Comment: @Dave thanks I now can call my method but the variables are undefined. How can I get the value of `this.$newElement` and `this.$element` which are located in the `Selectpicker` class?

Comment: check.. customRemove: function (ele) {
        ele.$newElement.remove();
        ele.$element.show();
    }

Comment: ele is undefined exception

Comment: not sure but i have added easily customRemove function in plugin . you can use it for quick reference until extend works.. see this jsfiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/pvT8Q/158/

Comment: @Dave thats because u added the function inside the plugin. I extended the plugin in my own js file to add a new function.

Comment: Did you manage to figure this out, @VDesign?

Comment: @user1987392 if you use the solution of Dave you can extend the plugin with your own method. For me this wasn't a solution because I needed the properties inside the class where the extended method has no access to

Comment: It doesn't help me either as I'm in the same boat as you: I wanted a custom `destroy` method that doesn't remove the original select DOM.

Comment: Then do like me and edit the jquery plugin itself, it is not a good method but it works

Answer (score 2):

I think, you have the correct answer in other your question:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852632/4928642

```
jQuery.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.prototype.customRemove = function () {
  this.$newElement.remove();
  this.$element.show();
};
```

then

```
$smth.selectpicker("customRemove");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could proxy the function with your own function using a mixin closure, like:

```
(function()
{
  // grab a reference to the existing remove function
  var _remove = $.fn.selectpicker.prototype.remove;

  // anything declared in here is private to this closure
  // so you could declare helper functions or variables
  // ...

  // extend the prototype with your mixin
  $.extend(true, $.fn.selectpicker.prototype, 
  {
    // this will replace the original $.fn.selectpicker.prototype.remove function
    remove: function () 
    {
      // call whatever code you want here
      // ...
      // ... like grabbing the DOM element
      // ...
      // then call the original remove function
      _remove.apply(this, arguments);

      // then call whatever you want here, like re-adding the DOM element
    }
  });
}());
```

Note: this will overweite the prototype for all Bootstrap selects and modify its behaviour.